# Where to find button ID in html inspect?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I am creating a python script to click a button on our online database at work and I am having difficulty finding the button id.
There is no mere `'button id='` and instead just wrapped in a bunch of div classes of the same name. 
Here is a sample inspection of google when I inspect the search button:
[image: inspect google search]

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# Go to your page url
driver.get('https://www.google.ca/')
# Get button you are going to click by its id ( also you could us find_element_by_css_selector to get element by css selector)
button_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='btnK']")
button_element.click()
```

Any insight would be appreciated; I am not familiar with html setups.

Comment: there is not button id added, instead you can use 'name' or 'class' attribute.

Comment: I can see <input name="btnI"........................ type="submit"... /> . This is a button in your website. Please refer to this link.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button

Comment: In python and selenium, you would input the button element id, can I input this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either xpath:

(//*[@value='Google Search'])[2]

or

(//*[@aria-label='Google Search'])[2]

to click on 'Google Search' button , Above people are suggesting 'name' attribute but this might break your code. So safe side you can use xpaths suggested by me because those attributes are being used by Google since long time. This text "Google Search" is what people see when they are on Google's home page. So Google might not change soon.

So try to pick attribute cautiously.  Enjoy

Comment: Thanks. I finally got my script to work in terms of opening a webpage, entering login and pressing a button. One issue - I have a button along a menu bar and when I run the script it is unable to locate the element. I use the xpath provided when copying, which works for other buttons but not along a menu bar.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQZXH.png

Comment: i did not understand your comment, please give me more details. if you have different question then search it or open new question on this platform. Do you need any help in xpath for any other page element ?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue! I learned the xpath is retrieved from right clicking on the inspected element and the error was a result of not giving the script enough time to pause before the webpage was loaded - time.sleep() fixed this. Thanks for all your help in this thread!

Answer (score 1):

Note: This explanation uses JavaScript, since the question tags JavaScript.

The highlighted `<input>` doesn't have and ID, so it can't be accessed with `document.getElementById()`.

It it does have a name "btnK", so you can use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to access it:

```
let myInput = document.querySelector('input[name="btnK"]');
```

This will retrieve the first `<input>` in the document with `name="btnK"`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not every HTML element has an ID. If it's not shown in the Developer Tools, it doesn't have it (it's empty string).

Comment: Thanks. So if I need to grab the link for the button I want to press, what can I put instead?

Comment: Its not Possible to directly press a button form URL.

Comment: @blacksheep Not possible using selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Locate it using css Selector or Xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='btnK']")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='btnK']")
```

If you are using selenium we driver with JavaScript, you can use below code to click on that button.

```
await driver.findElement(By.css("input[name='btnK']")).click();
```

Comment: Not familiar in these languages - how can I use this to determine the id?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. I am using python to automate the clicking of the button - any insight on it? I'll update my post to add sample code

Comment: My answer is already in selenium with python. If you are new in this follow some tutorials.

Comment: Please mark the answer as right if it helped you for future references.

Comment: First two are python one’s

Comment: Thanks, now it runs and opens Google! However it is unable to be 'scrolled into view'

Comment: Pls add your sample code in your question and to be scrolled into view use javascript executor